AssertionError in Django project
I am trying to test a API to create a company, but it gives me an assertion error. It says that I need to create a custom .create() method, but I have already defined that but am still getting the error.
serializer.py
class TaxInformationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TaxInformation
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return TaxInformation.objects.create(**validated_data)

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tax_information = TaxInformationSerializer()



    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ["brand_name", "legal_name", "mobile", "telephone_no", "fax", "status", "tax_information"]
        read_only_fields = ['user', 'created_at']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Automatically set the user to the request user
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if request and hasattr(request, 'user'):
            validated_data['user'] = request.user
        return super().create(validated_data)

        # Create the tax information instance
        tax_information_data = validated_data.pop('tax_information')
        # tax_information = TaxInformation.objects.create(**tax_information_data)
        tax_information_serializer = TaxInformationSerializer(data=tax_information_data)
        tax_information_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        tax_information = tax_information_serializer.save()

        # Create the company instance with the tax information
        instance = Company.objects.create(tax_information=tax_information, **validated_data)
        return instance

And the error is:

AssertionError at /datamanagement/company
The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `datamanagement.serializers.CompanySerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

I have already defined a custom create method but still getting the error.

you're calling super().create(validated_data)...

The subroutine CompanySerializer.create() has unreachable code. It doesn’t even finish before returning control.

Django Rest Serializer by default does not handle write/update operation on nested relations, so you can do one of these two:
1- Handle it manually with overriding create/update method.
You should iterate over TaxInformation objects in CompanySerializer create method and create objects one by one or use bulk create. also you might need override update method.
2- Use libraries like drf-writable-nested as mentioned in DRF documentation.
CompanySerializer class should look like this after:
from rest_framework import serializers
from drf_writable_nested.serializers import WritableNestedModelSerializer


class CompanySerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    tax_information = TaxInformationSerializer(many=True)

